# Trouble with UICollectionView : does not display labels of all of its cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have created a UICollectionView programmatically. I use a custom UICollectionViewCell subclass. Inside the cell class, I create a label with a class of my own (easier and quicker to set up its appearance). 
The problem I'm having is : for several cells, the collectionView does not layout the label content. I know that the data is here (print in the console) that is, the text property of the cell does contain the string data I want to show, but for some reason the collectionView does not display the label content. 
I tried with a simple test (print 'toto' inside the label) and I get a few toto's here and there, but not in all of the cells. As you can see I have 2 UICollectionViews inside the same ViewController, and this is why I test whether it's one or the other in the DataSource implementation.

Please tell me if you need more code.

Here's the code :

```
-(void)createBottomCollectionView {

    // Layout
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *collectionViewLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

    collectionViewLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    collectionViewLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0;

    // UICollectionView
    self.bottomCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 354+20, 320-2*20, 35) collectionViewLayout:collectionViewLayout];

    self.bottomCollectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.bottomCollectionView.bounces = YES;
    self.bottomCollectionView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = YES;
    self.bottomCollectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
    self.bottomCollectionView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.bottomCollectionView.dataSource = self;
    self.bottomCollectionView.delegate = self;

    [self.bottomCollectionView registerClass:[SetFormatCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:SetFormatCollectionViewCellIdentifier];

    // Background
    self.bottomCollectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [self.view addSubview:self.bottomCollectionView];

    [self.bottomCollectionView reloadData];
}
```

CollectionView datasource (dumb test with a "toto" value) in the real app I pull data with CoreData

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if (collectionView == self.bottomCollectionView) {

        SetFormatCollectionViewCell *cell = (SetFormatCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:SetFormatCollectionViewCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.text = @"toto";

        return cell;
    }
    if (collectionView == self.collectionView) {

        TrackingSetCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:TrackingSetCollectionViewCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

        return cell;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Custom Cell class :

```
@interface SetFormatCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *text;

@end

@implementation SetFormatCollectionViewCell

{
    FormatLabel *aFormatLabel;
}

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    if (self=[super initWithFrame:frame]) {

        // Initialization code

        aFormatLabel = [[FormatLabel alloc]initWithFrame:self.frame textColor:[UIColor blackColor] font:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ITCAvantGardeStd-Bk" size:22] alpha:1.0f border:YES];
        [self.contentView addSubview:aFormatLabel];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)prepareForReuse {

    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.text = @"";
}

-(void)setText:(NSString *)text {

    _text = [text copy];
    aFormatLabel.text = self.text;
}
```

FormatLabel Class (not important I think)

```
@interface FormatLabel ()
@property (assign,nonatomic) UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets;
@end

@implementation FormatLabel

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame textColor:(UIColor *)color font:(UIFont *)font alpha:(CGFloat)alphaValue border:(BOOL)withBorder{

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Set up
        self.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        self.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters;
        self.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

        self.textColor = color;
        self.alpha = alphaValue;
        self.font = font;
        if (withBorder) {
            self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
            self.layer.borderColor = color.CGColor;
        }
        self.edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(9, 6, 8, 6);
    }
    return self;
}
```

Thanks for helping

EDIT: for those who might have the same issue, I post 3 shots of the problem (you can find the answer just below). The 2nd shot contains colored cell the see the problem. The third shot is the one that I took just after accepting jmkk's answer.

Thanks for all the other answers!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you take a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: @batistomorrow are you sure your COllection view is getting the Cells of SetFormatCollectionViewCell. Debug it once

Comment: @thewormsterror I'd like to, but I need 10 points of reputation... In the picture you would see an horizontal collectionView, with all cells being there (if I were to set their background color you would see them all) but say only the first and the third cells would show up with the labels, while the others would stay empty.

Comment: @Jeev Yes I checked and the CV takes the good cells. I have the feeling there's an issue with prepareForReuse or something, but I cannot understand why it would layout some cells correctly, and mess things up with others.

Comment: @batistomorrow I upvoted, now you can post the SS

Comment: @batistomorrow have u made seperate XIB files for the Cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies with positioning of the FormatLabel view within the cell.
You're using cell's frame as the frame for the label, while what you need is the cell's bounds.

Cell's frame is relative to its superview, so applying the same position to cell's subview renders it offset relative to the cell itself.

Fix your code to do this:

```
 aFormatLabel = [[FormatLabel alloc]initWithFrame:self.bounds textColor:[UIColor blackColor] font:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ITCAvantGardeStd-Bk" size:22] alpha:1.0f border:YES];
```